# chrisjenx/calligraphy not work properly in my app tried so many answered

Tags: android, calligraphy

I tried so many examples and answered from other questions on this library but not working for me. I don't know what was happened with this?

**Application** class :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/choco-cookie.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".Utils.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Design.DashboardActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also attached to **Activity** :

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

And font available in `'assets/fonts/choco-cookie.ttf'`.

Problem is not changing fonts of all over app!

Comment: Try once, Remove folder of `fonts`, put font file directly.  and change path "choco-cookie.ttf" and `let me know where is your assets folder?`

Comment: ok I put it into directly in assets.

Comment: and set CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("choco-cookie.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());

Comment: but it is not work

Comment: Notice that Google is now providing similar (better?) functionality through last versions of Support Library. See https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you register your custom Application in the Manifest

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApplication" <----------- HERE
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```